First member state of entry mistake in the application (worried)
I realized I made a mistake on my application where I put Sweden as both first port of entry and final destination not realizing that a layover in Italy is actually requiring to go through pp control and get a stamped passport and so does my flight reservation show.
Will this be a problem or seen as false information? I don't want them to think I lied on the form or that my reservation is not legit (my reservation was through a reputable travel agency in my country of application). Really panicking here
Everyone and @phoog I would appreciate your insight. Thank you

I would appreciate insights from everyone @phoog is mentioned for optics.

You gave the copy of flight itenary, right? If that's the case, it should be fine as its obvious that its a genuine mistake. They won't hold it against you. It doesn't significantly change your trip.

Yes, my flight iternary showed Abu Dhabi to Stockholm through Rome. Thank you, really worried about misinterpretation as I dont think how Finland takes this information in relation to the flight

@AnishSheela Yes, my flight iternary showed Abu Dhabi to Stockholm through Rome. Thank you, really worried about misinterpretation as I dont think how Finland takes this information in relation to the flight

Did you get the visa? If not, it would be good to send an email to embassy about the mistake in the application.

@AnishSheela no I didnt, the problem is it has been 20 days already and the VFS confirmed they will receive the passport tomorrow and I only realized this now

Then I advise you to wait till tomorrow and see. They probably identified this (or not) and issued visa anyway.

ok thank you ,I am really worried it would be flagged as providing false information and if its denied for any other reason I wouldnt even know if they spotted that issue and/or if they flagged it as a deception

If you just submitted the application:

Send an email to embassy saying you misunderstood the point of entry
part and correct entry should be as per the flight tickets submitted.

If you received the visa:

Don't worry. They checked your tickets and found that everything is
OK. Just proceed as normal.


Thank you, what if the visa was rejected, would that have been a cause?. @ahishsheela

Unlikely. I suggest you to wait till tomorrow and then decide.

Visa refused but no indication if that was the reason. Could they have placed a ban due to contradictory information without me knowing? @anishsheela

What was the reason stated for refusal?

Not enough sustenance, information not reliable and no proof of leaving @anishsheela

@FGS then the port of entry data is the least of your worries.

@traveller please clarify what does this mean

@FGS They refused your visa for three material reasons (see here for a list of questions about refusals). Two of those reasons have nothing to do with the port of entry given, and information not reliable typically means they concluded you are not a genuine applicant. Your port of entry seems unlikely to have been a material factor in the refusal.

@Traveller got it thank you

@Traveller i honestly dont mind a refusal as I know my application is weak being a first time young traveller just worried about them banning me for putting wrong information

@FGS Shengen countries will tell you explicitly if you are banned. They will ban only for serious deception cases. Its not mentioned, you are ok. Try improving your situation and apply when its stronger.

@AnishSheela thank you for the information Anish its just that I have heard or read that the information of ban is not always explicitly mentioned to the applicant but I dont know the accuracy of that information
